# How do I get a list of AMIs taken from a given instance id using aws cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I have a Lambda function that takes AMI backups of running instances.  This is working well.

I'm trying to come up with a report that will tell me, for each instance, what is the latest AMI that was taken for that instance, and the date/time of the AMI.

I understand that there is no direct correlation of AMI to instance it was taken from, however, in my Lambda function, when the AMI is created, the instance id is recorred in the `Source`.  So, I'm trying to figure out how to do `aws ec2 describe-images` to retrieve a list of AMIs that have the relevant instance id recorded in the 'Source'.

Ideally, I'm lookig for a `describe-images` command that will give me the latest (most recent) AMI for a given instance id.

If I look at the list of AMIs that have been geneerated, the relevant AMIs have a `Source` that looks like this:

```
<redacted-my-account-id>/Lambda - i-<redacted my instance id> from 2020-09-16
```

Also, though there is a date in the `Source`, I think I want to look at `Creation Date`, as that has the date and time, in case more than one AMI was taken of a given instance on a particular day.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your requirement is:

- Loop through all AMIs
- Find those with a Source similar to `Lambda - i-123 from 2020-09-16`
- Of those, find the AMIs with the latest Creation Date for each source instance

Here is some code that will do it:

```py
import boto3
import re

ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')

response = ec2_client.describe_images(Owners=['self'])

latest_images = {} # eg {'i-1234abcd': '2020-09-17T22:20:09.000Z'}

for image in response['Images']:
    id_regex = re.search('Lambda - (i-[^ ]*) from', image['ImageLocation'])
    if id_regex:
        id = id_regex.group(1)
        if latest_images.get(id, '') < image['CreationDate']:
            latest_images[id] = image['CreationDate']

print(latest_images)
```

Please note that while you say "in case more than one AMI was taken of a given instance on a particular day", the `Source` is actually derived from the Image Name and it appears that it is not possible to create multiple AMIs with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

This code will read all the instance in you account and provide associate images you can also pass particulate instance id to get image.

```
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)
response = ec2.describe_instances()
inuse_image_list=[]
for reservation in response["Reservations"]:
    for instance in reservation["Instances"]:
        inuseimages=instance["ImageId"]
        inuse_image_list.append(inuseimages)
    
inuse_image_list = list(dict.fromkeys(inuse_image_list))
print("Fount {count} Inuse Images :-\n\n".format(count=len(inuse_image_list)),inuse_image_list,"\n\n")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-07ee44785d8aa1edz
```

and insert your own instance id it will return a JSON output with the ImageId field, which is that AMI that the instance is using.

Comment: The question is asking how to get a list of AMIs that were created from a specific EC2 instance. Your answer gives the AMI that the EC2 instance was originally created from.

Comment: "Ideally, I'm lookig for a describe-images command that will give me the latest (most recent) AMI for a given instance id."

Comment: If you are running a lambda that is creating the image of an instance why not write it in some persistent storage at that point? You can also add a time so you can sort it by said time.

Comment: That's a possibility, but then there is no connection to actual ami and whether it's currently available.  Once hte Lambda runs, at any time, that generated AMI could be deleted by anyone w/ the apporpriate privileges.  So, that's not the best methond.

Comment: Ultimately, I think I'm looking for how to describe-images and filter on the Source...can 't seem to figure it out, though....

Comment: I have done a lot around AMIs and never seen a "Source" like you are referring to. I think you should write it into a Dynamodb with a sort key on the date when the lambda kicks off the create image.

Comment: Ypu have never seen a 'Source'?  Just go to AWS EC2 Console->AMIs and the 4th column is 'Source'.

Comment: I am referring to the filter there is no Source filter on describe-images like you are trying to suggest. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-images.html